# How to make a new line counter in c? I have idea, but it doesn't work

Tags: c

I am learning C programming from a book "C Programming Language, 2nd Edition" and in the 1.5.3. paragraph there is a solution for creating counter of new lines, but it haven't worked, when I was trying to rewrite it and compile by myself.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c, nl;
    nl = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
    printf("%d\n", nl);
}
```

After trying to enter text on the next line and using CTRL + D, the programme returned 0. But I would like to see a number other than zero

Comment: Yes, I have tried to put new lines with Enter

Comment: To generate an EOF signal in Windows try CTRL+ Z followed by <Return>

Comment: Please note that your book, while generally good, is somewhat outdated. For example this style of defining functions is no longer valid. The correct incantation is `int main(void)`.

Comment: Why not search this site with `"[c] count newlines in file"` - there are already many answers to learn from. (put it in the searchbox at the top of the page...)

Comment: By the way try your code [online](https://onlinegdb.com/T5vq5q3CR), is it still not working?

Comment: "the programme returned 0" hmmm... are you talking about **return value** (aka exit code) or are you talking about what is printed to the terminal? That's different things

Answer (score 0):

> After trying to enter text on the next line and using CTRL + D, the programme returned 0”.

If you entered text and pressed <kbd>Control+D</kbd> (twice) without pressing Enter or Return, then you did not generate any newline characters, so the program’s count of zero is correct. A fragment of a line without a newline character does not count as a line. If you want a result other than zero, press Enter or Return before pressing <kbd>Control+D</kbd>. If you want to count a fragment of a line as a line, then you need to alter the program.

One way to alter the program to count fragmentary lines is to increment the count if any non-newline character is seen and then not increment it again until after a newline character is seen. Another way is to add one to the count after the loop if the last character seen before the `EOF` return value was not a newline character. For either of these, you will need an additional variable in the program to remember a little more information about the characters read.